# Mudando cor do site através de parâmetro GET

Tags: php, html, css, html5, reprodutor-de-video

Antes de tudo queria informar que eu sou iniciante em programação, estou aprendendo por conta.

Eu tenho uma dúvida, não quero códigos de mão beijada nem nada, apenas uma explicação para que eu possa colocar em prática.

Estava navegando na internet e entrei numa web-rádio, vi que no player deles é possível mudar a cor com um código na URL. Como isso é feito?

http://redeblast.com/player?color=FFCC00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é feito utilizando a variável global [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php). Com essa variável você pode identificar os parâmetros utilizados na *URL*. Ex:

**Url:** https://www.example.com/?foo=bar

```
var_dump( $_GET["foo"] ); //Output --> bar
```

Dessa forma você consegue passar qualquer valor, inclusive você pode utilizar o valor dessa variável em um código *CSS*

**Url:** https://www.example.com/?font-weight=bold&bg=F00&color=FFF

PHP 5.6 ou inferior

```
<style>
    body {
        font-weight: <?php echo isset($_GET["font-weight"]) ? $_GET["font-weight"] : "normal" ?>,
        background: #<?php echo isset($_GET["bg"]) ? $_GET["bg"] : "000" ?>,
        color: #<?php echo isset($_GET["color"]) ? $_GET["color"] : "FFF" ?>,
    }
</style>
```

PHP 7.0 ou superior

```
<style>
    body {
        font-weight: <?php echo $_GET["font-weight"] ?? "normal" ?>,
        background: #<?php echo $_GET["bg"] ?? "000" ?>,
        color: #<?php echo $_GET["color"] ?? "FFF" ?>,
    }
</style>
```

> *Dica:* Utilizando os [**operadores de comparação**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) ou [**null coalescing operator**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php) você definir uma cor ou outra característica padrão, caso o site não receba esses parâmetros.

Porém tenha cuidado como e onde utiliza esses valores. Algumas pessoas utilizam técnicas de [*Cross-site scripting*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) para ataques.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é feito pegando o parâmetro da URL com `$_GET['color']` e atribuindo a uma variável que será usada no PHP para definir a cor onde quiser. Exemplo:

```
$cor = $_GET['color'];
```

A variável `$cor` poderá ser aplicada no HTML da página onde quiser, por exemplo, como cor de fundo de uma `div`:

```
<div style="background-color: #<?=$cor?>"></div>
```

Como toda cor em hexadecimal é prefixada com `#`, basta adicionar o valor capturado da URL e acrescentar o símbolo `#` antes do valor.

Answer (score -1):

Apenas para complementar a resposta:

O PHP possui outras variáveis com usos semelhantes, o [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) passa dados através da url, o [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php) passa esses dados "escondidos" (ambos são eliminados ao mudar de página, por exemplo, se você estiver em ex1.php e passar os dados via GET ou POST para ex2.php os dados estarão lá, mas ao ir para ex3.php esses dados não existiram mais, a não ser que vocẽ os reenvie novamente) e o [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) que cria uma sessão com os dados que ficará salvos até ser excluídas (através de código) ou usuário sair do navegador

Essas variáveis são globais (pode ser acessado de qualquer parte do site) e do tipo array, assim para obter um GET, POST ou SESSION você deve passar um nome, por exemplo, `$_GET["exemplo"]` busca o valor do array get na posição que possui o nome exemplo

Para enviar dados do HTML para o PHP use a tag `<form>` especificando como você quer enviar os dados no `method` (POST ou GET), nos `input` use o atributo `name` para especificar o nome quando for pegar esse valor por exemplo:

```
<form action="pagina/de_destino.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="exemplo">
</form>
```

No PHP use `$_GET["exemplo"]` para pegar o valor enviado pelo usuário

O SESSION precisa precisa ser criado direto no php, por exemplo:

```
$_SESSION["exemplo"] = "valor do exemplo";
```